# How to find the Module ID of a dojo module

Tags: dojo, amd

I have a set of global javascript page resources that need to be managed from many different dojo classes. In older versions (dojo 1.6), I used the `declaredClass` property of a class instance to determine which class was attenpting to access the shared resource and act appropriately.

Now that I am using the AMD loader and have converted my modules appropriately, this technique no longer works.  In fact, it appears that there is no way of finding out what the module ID of a class instance is at runtime.  I have looked through the dojo 1.9 `dojo\_base\declare` code, but it appears that a unique identifier is *only* assigned when there is a common base class via the `c3mro` function.

Here are two examples of the seemingly counter-intuitive behavior of how `declaredClass` functions compared to the older versions of dojo.

Case 1: Two classes with a shared base class

**Base.js**

```js
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function (declare) {
    return declare(null, {        
    });
});
```

**ClassA.js** and **ClassB.js**

```js
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "./_Base"], function(declare, _Base) {
    return declare([_Base], {
    });
});
```

**Test Script**

```js
require(["myapp/test/ClassA", "myapp/test/ClassB"], function (A, B) {
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();

    console.log(a.declaredClass);
    console.log(b.declaredClass);
});
```

**Output**

```
uniqName_1
uniqName_1
```

If I change the test, so that `ClassA` and `ClassB` do not inherit from `_Base`, or use simple inheritance by passing in `_Base` as a single argument, rather than in an array, then I get `undefined` for an output.

**ClassA.js** and **ClassB.js**

```js
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "./_Base"], function(declare, _Base) {
    return declare(null, {
    });
});
```

or

```js
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "./_Base"], function(declare, _Base) {
    return declare(_Base, {
    });
});
```

**Test Output**

```
undefined
undefined
```

I can work around the problem by explicitly setting the `className` argument of the `declare()` function, but that is obviously discouraged in the interest of writing portable modules.

So, is there any way to know, from within a class instance, what module ID was used to instantiate that class?

**UPDATE**

The use case I am trying to support is for the `_Base` class to mediate access to some global resource.  Here is a skeleton of what the pre-1.7 logic is doing. Obviously I can create a different method of identifying the users of the resource, but I was curious if there was a way of adapting the pre-1.7 behavior into the AMD infrastructure.

**Base.js**

```js
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/kernel"], function (declare, kernel) {
    return declare(null, {
        activate: function(item) {
            // Get the set of current active items
            var activeItems = kernel.global.activeItems || {};

            // Disable anything that is currently active, unless it's for the
            // current instance
            for (var key in activeItems) {
                if (key !== this.declaredClass) {
                    activeItems[key].deactivate();
                }
            }

            // Activate and save the current item
            item.activate();
            activeItems[this.declaredClass] = item;

            kernel.global.activeItems = activeItems;
        },

        deactivate: function(item) {
            var activeItems = kernel.global.activeItems || {};
            if (activeItems[this.declaredClass]) {
                item.deactivate();
                delete activeItems[this.declaredClass];
            }
        }      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the only possible way is by using the `declare()` argument. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I actually think this is a good way to do it. If you rename your module, then the code that uses the `declaredClass` will still work.

Also, Dojo allows you to customize packages and choose which package name should be used and what the path to that package is. So that means you can have both `myPackage/ClassA`, but you can also name the package so you get `myExtremelyCoolPackage/ClassA`. If you don't have a static classname for that, then your code using that classname will actually break.

Besides that, classnames are almost not necessary in AMD, you don't need them to load your modules or in your declarative markup. The only reason they're there is to support legacy code which still relies on classnames. So if you really don't want to put it in your `declare()`, then it might be useful to say in what use case you want to use it.